Why does GIMP require such enormous font type sizes?
When adding text to an image in GIMP, one must specify enormous font sizes, well above 64pt, to even achieve a common typewriter size on the printed image. I am working with a image of about 6000 by 8000 pixels, set at a resolution of 300ppi, which produces a "printed" image of about 270 mm by 355 mm. Using very common fonts, such as Droid Sans, I have to use type sizes of about 78 or even 95 to be "printed" (that is, to appear on the virtual page) at about a normal 12pt size font.

FYI, we're having the same discussion by the same user at https://www.reddit.com/r/GIMP/comments/1dvlbhi/why_does_gimp_require_such_enormous_font_type/, with so far the same results - their numbers are wrong.

It doesn't  The problem is with your settings.  Create an A4 document 300ppi, and set the font size to "12pt".  Make sure the units are set to "pt", not "px".  It should be the correct size.

See this example here

Okey, my bad for not being precise and talking about "abouts". I know now what is going on, I shall write a self-answer.

Billy Kerr on the comments got it right. I thought that font sizes where always in "pt", never in "px", so I read "points" when the unit was "px". And there is the answer: if one chooses "px", the screen resolution is the measuring rule that GIMP uses. Then, if I set the font to 64 "px", it will look like 64 "pt" at 100% zoom, a pixel for a pixel, around one inch for the
uppercase "A".
So, here is the math right:
6473 x 8394  pixels image size
600x600 dpi.
274,02mm × 355,35mm  print size.
My screen has about 105 dpi (900 pixels in a 8.5 inch screen).
A font that is 77 "px" will have capital "A" tallness, at 100% zoom, around 0.73 inches, or 18.6mm.
But printed that is practically 6 times less: around 3 mm. Like a small font on a book.
That is big.

Just to avoid a possible additional misconception on your part: at a font size of 77 pixels, the capital A is not supposed to be 77 pixels tall - the font size is the glyphs body height, which includes ascender and descender: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_height_(typography). And in the context of a 600 ppi image, a 77 pixel font size is tiny indeed - about 9,36 points, 0,13 inches, 3,3 millimeters, and the glyphs will be smaller even because almost none stretch over the full body height.

1. Your numbers are wrong.

6000x8000 has a proportion of 6/8 or .75
270/355 = .76. Is not very different, but starts to show that the numbers are not right.



6000x8000 at 300 PPI = 20x26.66 Inches or 508x677mm. Now it is clear you are resampling your image almost two times.
Your image is at 564PPI.

2. 12 Pts size at 300PPI

72 Pts is = 300Pixels
72/12 = 6
12 Pts = 300/6 = 50 Pixels


To me. The sizes match good enough.
3. Define Typewriter size.
If you are printing the page, there is a chance more resampling is applied if you have some "fit to page" feature on the printer dialog box.
I do not understand what is your virtual page. If you are referring to a "preview", we need to know the scale and the screen size. It is not the same to see a preview on a cellphone as a 28-inch monitor.
